# Change the character length of single line strings using regex

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics, genbank

I have extracted a sequence from a genbank file that consists of single lines of strings with 60 bases (with a \n at the end). How to modify the sequence using perl so that it prints 120 bases for each line using regex and not bioperl. 
original format:

```
    1 agatggcggc gctgaggggt cttgggggct ctaggccggc cacctactgg tttgcagcgg
   61 agacgacgca tggggcctgc gcaataggag tacgctgcct gggaggcgtg actagaagcg
  121 gaagtagttg tgggcgcctt tgcaaccgcc tgggacgccg ccgagtggtc tgtgcaggtt
  181 cgcgggtcgc tggcgggggt cgtgagggag tgcgccggga gcggagatat ggagggagat
  241 ggttcagacc cagagcctcc agatgccggg gaggacagca agtccgagaa tggggagaat
  301 gcgcccatct actgcatctg ccgcaaaccg gacatcaact gcttcatgat cgggtgtgac
  361 aactgcaatg agtggttcca tggggactgc atccggatca ctgagaagat ggccaaggcc
  421 atccgggagt ggtactgtcg ggagtgcaga gagaaagacc ccaagctaga gattcgctat
  481 cggcacaaga agtcacggga gcgggatggc aatgagcggg acagcagtga gccccgggat
```

I only managed to make them into strings with the length of 60 characters. Still trying to figure out how to make them 120 characters long.

```
my @lines= <$FH_IN>;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line=~ m/(^\s*\d+\s)[acgt]{10}\s/) {
            $line=~ s/$1//;
            $line=~ s/ //g;
            print $line;
    }
```

}

example of input:

```
agatggcggcgctgaggggtcttgggggctctaggccggccacctactggtttgcagcgg
agacgacgcatggggcctgcgcaataggagtacgctgcctgggaggcgtgactagaagcg
gaagtagttgtgggcgcctttgcaaccgcctgggacgccgccgagtggtctgtgcaggtt
cgcgggtcgctggcgggggtcgtgagggagtgcgccgggagcggagatatggagggagat
ggttcagacccagagcctccagatgccggggaggacagcaagtccgagaatggggagaat
gcgcccatctactgcatctgccgcaaaccggacatcaactgcttcatgatcgggtgtgac
aactgcaatgagtggttccatggggactgcatccggatcactgagaagatggccaaggcc
atccgggagtggtactgtcgggagtgcagagagaaagaccccaagctagagattcgctat
```

which has 60 bases for each single line string.

Update (still not giving seq lines with 120 bases long):

```
my @seq_60;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
        if ($line=~ m/(^\s*\d+\s)[acgt]{10}\s/) {
                $line=~ s/$1//;
                $line=~ s/ //g;
                push (@seq_60, $line);
        }
}

my @output;
for (my $pos= 0; $pos< @seq_60; $pos+= 2) {
        push (@output, $seq_60[$pos] . $seq_60[$pos+1]);
}

print @output;
```

Comment: some input expected output would be helpful!!!!

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/68

Comment: How to write a code to do that

Comment: its the regex.which language are you using?

Comment: It is perl that I am using

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see any code that suggests you might have tried to solve the problem yourself...

Comment: @ialarmedalien I only managed to modify the sequence part of genbank file into strings of 60 characters long. Just updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
s/(^|\n)([^\n]{60})\n/$1$2/g
```

**In action:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my $str = q/agatggcggcgctgaggggtcttgggggctctaggccggccacctactggtttgcagcgg
agacgacgcatggggcctgcgcaataggagtacgctgcctgggaggcgtgactagaagcg
gaagtagttgtgggcgcctttgcaaccgcctgggacgccgccgagtggtctgtgcaggtt
cgcgggtcgctggcgggggtcgtgagggagtgcgccgggagcggagatatggagggagat
ggttcagacccagagcctccagatgccggggaggacagcaagtccgagaatggggagaat
gcgcccatctactgcatctgccgcaaaccggacatcaactgcttcatgatcgggtgtgac
aactgcaatgagtggttccatggggactgcatccggatcactgagaagatggccaaggcc
atccgggagtggtactgtcgggagtgcagagagaaagaccccaagctagagattcgctat/;

$str =~ s/(^|\n)([^\n]{60})\n/$1$2/g;
say $str;
```

**Output:**

```
agatggcggcgctgaggggtcttgggggctctaggccggccacctactggtttgcagcggagacgacgcatggggcctgcgcaataggagtacgctgcctgggaggcgtgactagaagcg
gaagtagttgtgggcgcctttgcaaccgcctgggacgccgccgagtggtctgtgcaggttcgcgggtcgctggcgggggtcgtgagggagtgcgccgggagcggagatatggagggagat
ggttcagacccagagcctccagatgccggggaggacagcaagtccgagaatggggagaatgcgcccatctactgcatctgccgcaaaccggacatcaactgcttcatgatcgggtgtgac
aactgcaatgagtggttccatggggactgcatccggatcactgagaagatggccaaggccatccgggagtggtactgtcgggagtgcagagagaaagaccccaagctagagattcgctat
```

**Explanation:**

```
(^|\n)      : group 1, start of string or line break
(           : start group 2
  [^\n]{60} : anything that is not a line break 60 times
)           : end group 2
\n          : line break
```

**Edit according to comment:**

Join lines by pair:

```
my @out;
for (my $i = 0; $i < @arr; $i += 2) {
    chomp($in[$i]);
    push @out, $in[$i] . $in[$i+1];
}
```

Comment: In my input, every single line string has 60 bases in an array. Do I need to join them into one string?

Comment: @zebra: If you have an array of lines, join the lines by pair, see my edit.

Comment: I have adjusted my code with your suggestion, but it still doesn't change, only printing 60 characters. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the line reading and writing at the same time, and store the previous line in a variable. See the code comments for an explanation of what is happening:

```
my $prev;
while (<$FH_IN>) {
    next unless /\w/; # make sure the lines have some content
    # remove the line endings
    chomp;
    # chop off the first 6 characters (the base numbers) - format is 4 chars that
    # can be numbers or spaces, a digit, and a space
    $_ =~ s/^[\s\d]{4}\d\s//g;
    # remove the spaces between bases
    $_ =~ s/\s//g;
    # have we got a saved line?
    if ($prev) {
        # print out saved line and this line
        print $prev . $_ . "\n";
        # delete the saved line $prev
        $prev = '';
    }
    else {
        # if we don't have a saved line, save this line
        $prev = $_;
    }
}
```